# Jenkins websphere deployer plugin configuration

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and I am doing a POC for auto deployment to WAS server after the successful build in Jenkins.

I found 'Websphere Deployer' plugin as useful and started working on it and I am facing some issue.

Below are the steps I followed.

1. I deployed the Jenkins in my local host tomcat 7.0.64 and I am able
   to run it.
2. I configured a maven spring project from my local workspace and I am
   able to build it successfully.
3. I have added  the post build action to add the 'Deploy to IBM Websphere Application server' and provided the server details.
4. To use this plug in, as per the plugin documentation I added the WAS jar files(`com.ibm.ws.admin.client_x.x.x.jar, com.ibm.ws.orb_x.x.x.jar`) to C`:\Users\xxx\.jenkins\plugins\websphere-deployer\WEB-INF\lib`
5. When I click test connection, I am getting the following message

> Cannot find the required IBM WebSphere Application Server jar files in
>   '\plugins\websphere-deployer\WEB-INF\lib\'
>   Please copy them from IBM WebSphere Application Server (see plugin
>   documentation)

(Note: When I tried copying these jar files to `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64\webapps\jenkins-war\WEB-INF\lib` folder, while restarting the server I am getting

> org.apache. catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile.
>   com.ibm.ws.admin.client_7.0.0 jar not loaded. See servlet spec 3.0
>   offending class javax.servlet.Servlet.class** and getting the same
>   above error message when ckicking 'Test Connection')

What is wrong with my set up and Where exactly I need to place the jar files?
 Thanks

Comment: No need to copy to C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64\webapps\jenkins-war\WEB-INF\lib .. Jenkins picks from JENKINS_HOME directory.. Do you have use home property in your machine?

Comment: After trying so many things I tried placing jars in C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64\webapps\jenkins-war\WEB-INF\lib. But it didn't work. Can you please explain what is home property and how to set it?

Comment: http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2012/07/how-to-set-users-home-folder-via-group-policy-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the admin & orb jar files to the "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64\webapps\jenkins-war\plugins\websphere-deployer\WEB-INF\lib" location in your case. They cannot be placed in the jenkins lib since the plugin will not be able to find them.